# Puppeteer Sharp: avoid downloading Chromium (bundle Chromium locally)

Tags: c#, puppeteer, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

I'm using `Puppeteer Sharp` in my .NET application to do some webpage automation tasks. However, I have to deploy my app in an environment that only has intranet access, which means Puppeteer's `BrowserFetcher` class is unable to download Chromium from the internet, since it cannot access the Chromium repositories.

Is it possible to bundle a copy of Chromium with my app, so Puppeteer does not have to download it? How would I do that? I'm not finding much in the docs about this...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the [LaunchOptions.ExecutablePath](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.LaunchOptions.html#PuppeteerSharp_LaunchOptions_ExecutablePath) property. If you use `ExecutablePath` you don't even need to call `BrowserFetcher`. It would look something like this:

```
var options = new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    ExecutablePath = "<CHROME.EXE FULL PATH>"
};

using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should I download the package from tho? Will any copy of Chromium do, or is it better to obtain a specific version?

Comment: Good question. You can see the version mapping here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.10.0/docs/api.md so you can download a compatible version here https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/en/

Comment: Surely you *shouldn't* call `BrowserFetcher` if you want to avoid a download.